# Do you get 5 points for any question asked?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If I ask any question will my reputation automatically increase by five points?

Hopefully this question should answer itself

Comment: When you asked this question, did it increase?

Comment: No :-(  Dr badp answered correctly :-)

Answer (score 5):

No. You get 5 points per question upvote. [Read the FAQ.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Apart from on meta where you get 10 points per question upvote

Comment: Just to remind: Community-wiki posts don't produce rep points.